# ionic2 set cache view when triggering the button

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

```
<button class="alt-button" ion-item detail-none (click)="goToAbout()" clear small >
    <ion-icon  name='person' item-left></ion-icon>About us</button>
```

Button action

```
goToAbout() {
        this.menu.close();
        // close the menu and Goto About page 
        this.app.getRootNav().push(AboutPage);
    }
```

api call

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
this.loading.present();
        this.aboutservice.getPost().then(
        response => { 
            this.items = response
            this.loading.dismiss();
        },
        error=>{
            this.error = error
            this.showError('There was problem with server');
            this.loading.dismiss();
        });
}
```

it loads the api data everytime,but I want to load api data once and same button action i have used for sidemenu,Its working fine.please give any idea.

Comment: where's the api call code?

Comment: i have updated the code

Comment: i have placed the api call in construtor,still loading is appear

Answer (score 0):

It seems strange behavior according to the doc here.

*ionViewDidLoad*

> Runs when the page has loaded. This event only happens once per page
>   being created. If a page leaves but is cached, then this event will
>   not fire again on a subsequent viewing. The ionViewDidLoad event is
>   good place to put your setup code for the page.

But you can use it inside the `constructor()` as shown below.

```
constructor() {

  //your Api call here
  }
```

Comment: The solution is then you have to stop the app and strat it again using > `ionic serve` . It seems you're having browser cache corruption issue or like that.Start an app A-Z.